# Query tabels to sort sums across rows and count based on a value in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Here is my problem. i have 3-5 persons that is going to set a grade on one person and they use their own individual row to do so, and what I'm having trouble to do is to sum and average the grade from individual data across multiple rows on the same table.

in the select new statement i have made a pseudo answer of what i want

```
    var users = from workRew in db.Reviews
                select new
                {
                    UserID = workRew.UserID.DistinctOfSomeSort
                    AvgGrade = workRew.Grade.Sum/CountOfSomeSort
                };
```

Here i a illustration.
So if i have this table

```
| SomeID | UserID | Grade |
|   1    |   2    |   3   |
|   2    |   3    |   1   |
|   3    |   2    |   1   |
```

And this is the output i want from the LINQ query on the above (In theory ateast)

```
| UserID | AvgGrade |
|   2    |    2     |
|   3    |    1     |
```

EDIT: Simplified the whole case, to a great extent.

Comment: ...your join between the tables is on which fields? Right now you're mixing them all together.

Comment: some code is theoretical atm. so some joins and froms are wrongly placed and do not have an impact on what I want to do anyways, which is to add all the Grades with the same username, and count how many grades i added.

Comment: Group by userId. I'd make this a full answer, but there's no way I'll post a LINQ group by without VS to keep me straight. It'll have to wait till I'm at a desktop.

Comment: Fixed some of the code, so its more on track when reading the form/where statements. I'l fix a better illustration of what i want to achieve. and hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look something like this fragment:

```
group by user.UserID
select new
{
   User = user.UserID
   TotGradeCount = workRew.Grade.Sum()
   Graders = workRew.Grade.Count()
}
```